# Updating owned-owned entities in EF Core 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have an entity with nested value objects - i.e. an entity, which contains an owned type, which contains an owned type.

```
public class User {                           // entity
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public Token Token { get; private set; }
  // other stuff...
}

public class Token {                         // value object (owned type)
  public Hash Hash { get; private set; }
  // other stuff...
}

public class Hash {                          // value object (owned-owned type)
  // other stuff...
}
```

Updating the owned types doesn't work due to a [bug in EF Core 2.2](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12118). The workarounds in that github issue do not work for me.

I think the reason is I get the `user` entity via `UserManager<T>` instead of `DbContext`. But it uses the context anyway (which is scoped by the IoC container as per-request, so it's the same context whether I use `UserManager` or `Context`).

I tried this:

```
// ...get user from UserManager (I can't change that)
_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;
if (user.Token != null) _context.Entry(user.Token).State = EntityState.Detached;
if (user.Token?.Hash != null) _context.Entry(user.Token.Hash).State = EntityState.Detached;
user.createNewToken();
_context.Update(user);
_context.Update(user.Token);
_context.Update(user.Token.Hash);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But I get:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a primary key or any other way of uniquely identifying the user in the database? You could possible use your User object to retrieve an attached representation of the same object from the database, if that helps.

Comment: @Jonny Yep tried that too, doesn't work :(